# Set network Credentials for stackExchange Redis connection multiplexer

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis, webproxy

I have setup a remote redis server.

The client uses a web proxy to connect to the internet.

How do I set the StackExchange.redis ConnectionMultiplexer to use a webProxy in C#?

The following is my ConnectionMultiplexer code:

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("xxxx:6379,password=xxxxx");
```

Answer (score 0):

The StackExchange.redis ConnectionMultiplexer connects to Redis using a Port. A firewall change is needed on a client to connect to 6379. If needed on port 80 a simple web service like Redisd or Webdis can be setup. This will allow you to use http web request to get and set keys.